# Create blog post from external source and set publication date

Tags: posts, publish, scheduled-posts

I'm building a script which creates new blog posts from an external source. my code is as follows:

```
    // Load WordPress
    require_once '../../wp-load.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
    // Set the timezone so times are calculated correctly
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    // Create post
    $id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title'    => $headline,
        'post_content'  => $body,
        'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'draft',
    ));

if($id){
    // Set category - create if it doesn't exist yet
    wp_set_post_terms($id, wp_create_category($region), 'category');
    // Add meta data, if required
    add_post_meta($id, 'meta_key', $metadata);
    echo $open_wrap."<h2>Success!</h2>
    <p>The post has been added to the Bulletins Category as a <strong>draft</strong>.<br>
    Please $wp_url to Publish or Schedule the post.</p> 
    ".$close_wrap;

} else {
    echo "WARNING: Failed to insert post into WordPress\n";
}
```

I'd like to allow the user to set the publication date, so they can create the post and it will publish automatically on that date.

Is there a wordpress function for adding a publication date?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are loading WordPress by including the core files, there should be something wrong at that point.

Anyway, to schedule an event, you can use [`wp_schedule_single_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event). This function accepts 3 arguments:

```
wp_schedule_single_event( $timestamp, $hook, $args );
```

In your case, you can wrap `wp_insert_post` in a function, and then call it when the time arrives:

```
// Use this instead of wp_insert_post
wp_schedule_single_event( 'SET THE TIME HERE', 'schedule_my_post' );

// Add an action that runs the function
add_action( 'schedule_my_post','publish_my_post' );

// Now, do the actual publish
function publish_my_post($args){
    wp_insert_post($args);
}
```

Done.